# Insert multiple values with the same foreign key

Tags: sqlite, sql-insert, common-table-expression, union-all, cross-join

I have two tables that reference each other:

```
CREATE TABLE Room
    room_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    room_name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL;

CREATE TABLE Item
    item_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    room_id INTEGER,
    item_name TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY (room_id) REFERENCES Room (room_id) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

Now I want to add a new room and add a few dozen items to go into it.

```
INSERT INTO Room(room_name) VALUES ('Living Room');
```

Let's say I don't know how many rooms there are, and I just want to put stuff into the living room. To do that, I need to select the right `room_id`. For a single item this is not too bad:

```
INSERT INTO Item(room_id, item_name)
    SELECT room_id, 'Couch' AS item_name FROM Room WHERE room_name = 'Living Room';
```

But what if I want to insert a bunch of values simultaneously. I tried using `last_insert_rowid`, but that does not treat the entire `INSERT` as a single transaction. In other words, the last ID keeps incrementing

```
INSERT INTO Item (room_id, item_name)
  VALUES
    (last_insert_rowid(), 'Chair'),
    (last_insert_rowid(), 'TV'),
    (last_insert_rowid(), 'Carpet');
```

I would like to avoid having to use the `SELECT` on each new row. Is there a way to insert multiple values into `Item`, while referencing the last known `room_id` in `Room`?

Something in the nature of a `CROSS JOIN` would likely be very useful, but I don't know how to get the constants to behave in that case

The end result I am looking for is for `Room` to look like this:

```
room_id | room_name
--------+-----------
      1 | Living Room
```

And `Item` like this:

```
item_id | room_id | item_name
--------+---------+-----------
      1 |       1 | Chair
      2 |       1 | TV
      3 |       1 | Carpet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CROSS` join of the id that you get from the new room to a CTE that returns the items that you want to insert:

```
WITH cte(item_name) AS (VALUES ('Chair'), ('TV'), ('Carpet'))
INSERT INTO Item (room_id, item_name)
SELECT r.room_id, c.item_name
FROM Room r CROSS JOIN cte c
WHERE r.room_name = 'Living Room';
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4e3eeb0daab8c33d73afdd3ceca50832).

If you are using a version of SQLite that does not support CTEs use `UNION ALL` in a subquery:

```
INSERT INTO Item (room_id, item_name)
SELECT r.room_id, c.item_name
FROM Room r 
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 'Chair' item_name UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'TV' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Carpet'
) c
WHERE r.room_name = 'Living Room';
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=33144540507742182ea760db9d10f1ca).

Comment: I didn't realize you can make a CTE from literals like that with `VALUES`. The is great. Thanks.